# How to set paper size using html css?

Tags: html, css, printing

I want print html to label printing using thermal printer but paper size is so difficult to adjust.

this is a few of my css code for printing

```
@media print {
 @page { 
  size: 5cm 7cm portrait; 
  margin: 0 1mm 0 1mm;
 }
 body{
  width:100%; 
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
 }
}
```

below is preview i wanted to print

[this what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4n7l.jpg)

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mturjak/2wk6Q/1949/

You can set your style and grab it

Answer (score 0):

Try this for set paper size A4.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="subpage">Page 1/2</div>    
    </div>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="subpage">Page 2/2</div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    font: 12pt "Tahoma";
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.page {
    width: 21cm;
    min-height: 29.7cm;
    padding: 2cm;
    margin: 1cm auto;
    border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.subpage {
    padding: 1cm;
    border: 5px red solid;
    height: 256mm;
    outline: 2cm #FFEAEA solid;
}

@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 0;
}
@media print {
    .page {
        margin: 0;
        border: initial;
        border-radius: initial;
        width: initial;
        min-height: initial;
        box-shadow: initial;
        background: initial;
        page-break-after: always;
    }
}
```