# HTML main and footer tag not rendering correctly in PDF

Tags: html, css, pdf-generation

I have a html document which consists of a series of divs (see below); Each div has the a `page-break-after-always` class which is used to groupd desired content to each page when rendered to a PDF.

The content class just centers the main element in its parent and I have a footer element styled so it sticks to the bottom of its parent.

My markup:

```
<div class="page-break-after-always relative">

  <main class="content"> 
    /* content */
  </main>

  <footer class="bottom">
   content which spans the full width
  </footer>
</div>

<div class="page-break-after-always">
   /* same as above */
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .page-break-after-always { 
    page-break-after: always; 
    height: auto 
  }
    
  .relative {
    position: relative;
  }

   .bottom {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

What happens when rendered though the content is not centered **AND** the footer doesn't stick to the bottom, contrary to the dev tools showing the footer sticking to the bottom. See my image, content is off center and you can see how far above the footer is from the bottom.

[image]

Is there some CSS for PDF that can solve this?

Comment: Have you tried to set a page size with something like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753445/how-to-set-paper-size-using-html-css)?  What are you using to convert it to PDF?

Comment: @stdunbar I'll try that! Will that solve the footer problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do what you need in a HTML Page but since its for PDF printing then its best to emulate the way its internally held in a PDF.

First a PDF defines a Page then objects to be placed at page co-ordinates without reflow or margins or tabs etc.

[image]

so using those principles one way to do that is:-

```
<html><head><style>
div.heading, div.footing {
    display: none;
}
@media print {
  @page {
    /* For different margins – use the standard CSS margin property: north, east, south, west, here it is one value */
    margin: 0!important;
    size: A4 Portrait;
  }
  html { background-color: #FFFFDD; }
  body { margin: 0!important; }
  .page {
      page-break-before: always;
  }
  div.heading {
      position: fixed;
      color: #0066FF;
      top: -5mm;
      left: 90mm;
            display: block;
  }
  div.content {
      position: relative;
      top: 20mm;
      left: 12.7mm;
      height: 27.7cm;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  div.footing {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      display: block;
  }
}
</style></head><body>
<div class="heading"><h1><center>Doc Heading</center></h1></div>
<div class="footing"><i style="color: #FF0066; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold"><pre>Doc footing                                                  content which spans the full width</pre></i></div>

<div class="page">
  <div class="content">.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 10.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 20.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 30.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 40.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 1.<br>.body text 50.<br></div>
</div>

<div class="page">
  <div class="content">.body text 2.<br>.body text 2.<br>.body text 2.<br>.body text 2.<br>.body text 2.<br>.body text 2.<br>.body text 2.<br>.body text 2.<br>.body text 2.<br>.body text 60.<br></div>
</div>

<div class="page">
  <div class="content">.body text 3.<br>.body text 3.<br>.body text 3.<br>.body text 3.<br>.body text 3.<br>.body text 3.<br>.body text 3.<br>.body text 3.<br>.body text 3.<br>.body text 70.<br></div>
</div>

</body></html>
```